# SMACK and Google Hangouts - Listen for invitations

Tags: java, android, xmpp, smack

Does anyone know whether or not SMACK can listen for group hangout invitations?

I have tried adding a listener

`MultiUserChat.addInvitationListener(...)`

I have tried joining a room manually and then in code tried:

`for (String room : MultiUserChat.getJoinedRooms(connection, connection.getUser())) {
    dLog(String.format("%s -> getJoinedRooms? %s", getUsername(), room));
}`

But I never see anything in the logs. So the Question is, can SMACK be used to listen for group chats in Google Hangouts?

I have been over the relevant links, like: https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.0/documentation/extensions/muc.html and https://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/4.0.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MultiUserChat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike GTalk, Hangouts is not based on XMPP. So you can't use an XMPP library like Smack here.

Comment: But normal chats work just fine!?! I guess group hangouts are not based on XMPP multi user chat.